# Node MSSQL "TypeError: req.query is not a function" error

Tags: sql-server, node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

var sql = require("mssql");

var dbconfig = {
 server: "srv-sql-002.alpaca.int",
 user: "stagiair1",
 password: "Rainbow80",
 options: {
    database: "Calamares"
 }
};



/* GET api listing. */
router.get('/', (sqlReq, res) => {
 res.send('api works');
});

// Get all posts
 router.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
sql.connect(dbconfig, function (err) {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    request.query('SELECT TOP (10) u.* FROM [Alg].[User] AS u;', function (err, recordset) {
        console.log("in query function");
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset));
        }
    });
    request.query();
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

This code generates the error, any idea what I'm doing wrong? 
It does work in an Node console application, but not in a web application as an API.
Thanks in advance!

(In order to add all my code I had to add some more text....
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean interdum, elit sit amet rhoncus placerat, tellus lorem aliquet sapien, ac rhoncus ipsum turpis nec metus. Donec sit amet mi enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec hendrerit felis eget semper mollis. Aliquam consequat nibh in dolor sollicitudin dictum. Mauris non mollis est. Vestibulum dictum mi efficitur, maximus leo id, ultrices urna. Cras aliquam libero nec odio porttitor, in placerat tortor aliquam. Aenean enim eros, sagittis nec aliquet nec, placerat id nunc. Nunc dolor purus, blandit sit amet odio viverra, ultrices fermentum nisi. Nullam dictum vitae augue eu semper. Nam vulputate ipsum vel lorem pretium, vel efficitur orci fringilla. Aliquam diam erat, rhoncus vel lacus laoreet, eleifend ultrices augue. Ut vitae sapien magna. Sed eleifend, tellus quis commodo elementum, felis tortor ultricies nibh, nec congue tortor ipsum eget erat.)

**Updated**

Changed code to the working version, just tried 100 different combinations and this one works. 
Thanks everyone for the help!!!!

Comment: req is the express js request object, not a db object .. are you sure you don't want to do something like db.query?

Comment: var req = new sql.Request(conn); I use it like this, got it from a Youtube tutorial and it should work... It does in a Node console application I build

Answer (score 0):

You should name your database access request object something other than `req` (`sqlReq` or something), which is an `express` request object in this context.

Edit: I've looked at the npm page for examples, you should try replacing `sqlQuery.query` with `conn.query` - if this works you don't need the `req`/`sqlReq` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! But I still get the same error... Any more ideas?

Comment: `sqlReq.query` is not a function?

Comment: Yes! Any ideas?

Comment: there's an issue with the sql request. can you add the code where sql is defined?

Comment: I updated my post with the whole code, sorry for the Lorem Ipsum but there wasn't enough 'text' in the post...

Comment: Is sqlReq defined and connected to the db before you use it? Can you inspect it or log it in the console?

Comment: After "conn.connect" it's a whole lot bigger, but too big to post here.. But it seems to be connected to the db, the "conn.connect' doesn't returns an error

Comment: I changed the sqlReq in the router params back to just req and now the page keeps loading but doesn't give me an error... Only when I refresh the page it gives me the error: "ConnectionError: Database is already connected! Call close before connecting to different database." In Postman it also just keeps loading...

Comment: What should I try?

Comment: try replacing `sqlQuery.query` with `conn.query` - if this works you don't need the req/sqlReq object.

Comment: any luck trying that?

Comment: Again the problem with that the page just keeps loading, on refresh the error "Database is already connected!". And it still doesn't return my data...

Comment: I'm also getting the error in my chrome console: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

In my Case it was solved when i tried async /await in connection and query function.